# Type casting error in C

Tags: c, casting

I am trying to implement a simple C program to teach myself about pointers. I am getting a `c warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]` whenever I run it. I have an idea of the issue,but am beginner in C and I don't know how to tackle it. Please assist.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

void print_time(long input, int *hours, int *minutes, int * seconds);

int main() {

   //char message[30];
   //int message_size;
   int hours, minutes, seconds;
   long input;

   printf("Enter the number of seconds: ");
   scanf("%ld",&input);

   print_time(input, &hours, &minutes, &seconds);

   printf("The equivalent is: %d hour(s), %d minute(s), %d second(s).", hours,minutes,seconds);
   return 0;
}

void print_time(long input, int *hours, int *minutes, int * seconds){
    hours = (int)floor(input/3600);
    minutes = (int)floor((input%3600)/60);
    seconds = (int)input - (hours*3600)-(minutes*60);

}
```

Comment: Pay attention to the warning, specifically the line it points out. Then the problem becomes obvious.

Comment: There is a reason for the warning. As a general rule: **Only** cast if 1) The cast is really required _and_ 2) You **fully** understand all implications _and_ 3) you **completely** accept them.

Comment: @Olaf There is no problem with casts in this.

Comment: @EOF: They are useless, though, as is  the use of floating point functions. And passing `input` as `long` is also useless. Not only there is no guarantee it ha a larger range than `int`, the last cast will actively do harm.

Comment: @Olaf: I'll take that back: The compiler would've probably complained even louder about assigning a `double` to an `int *`, since that is not even defined.

Comment: @EOF: To be fair, that is another issue, I did not even think about.

Comment: The calls to `floor()` are superfluous.  @Olaf has mentioned it, but didn't explicitly state it.  In integer division, the result is an `int`.  The result of `3700 / 3600` is `1`, `7512 / 3600` is `2`, and `3599 / 3600` is `0`.  And in this case, the [`div()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) would be very useful to get the quotient and remainder in one operation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: But `div` would reduce readability. As the code is not to be optimised, I'd leave it with the seperate operators and possible compiler optimisation.

Comment: In defense of the OP's casts: in this case, since he didn't really need `floor()`, it's true, he could have gotten away without the casts.  But Microsoft compilers, at least, tend to warn about float → int conversions, so if you write, for example, `int i = sqrt(145.)`, you have to insert an `(int)` cast to silence the warning.  I suspect that's what motivated the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead...

```
void print_time(long input, int *hours, int *minutes, int * seconds){
    *hours = (int)floor(input/3600);
    *minutes = (int)floor((input%3600)/60);
    *seconds = (int)input - (hours*3600)-(minutes*60);
}
```

You're passing pointers to integers and treating them like integers.

Comment: The problem is not *casting*, it's *assignment without casting*.

Comment: \*sigh\*, no. The code is not treating pointers as integers, it's trying to *assign* integers to pointers. If anything, the problem would be treating integers as pointers.